# Ler dados de porta serial com javascript, node

Tags: javascript, node.js, serial, usb

**Problema :**

Buscar uma alternativa para ler dados de uma porta COM5 usb, com o bound 115200.

Estou trabalhando com um *sensor libelium waspmote*, medidor de corrente alternada, esse sensor emite dados via *usb*, e preciso usar esses dados em uma *aplicação front-end em angular 5* que estou contruíndo.

**Atualizaçao da solução encontrada :**
serialport em nodejs,

No final do post, tem uma resposta da solução encontrada em mais detalhes.

**npm install --save-dev serialport**

```
 // This configurations uses serialport lib to catch usb values in serial COM (N) and baudRate
/* eslint-disable node/no-missing-require */
'use strict';

// Use a Readline parser

const SerialPort = require('serialport');
const parsers = SerialPort.parsers;

// Use a `\r\n` as a line terminator
const parser = new parsers.Readline({
  delimiter: '\r\n'
});

const port = new SerialPort('COM3', {
  baudRate: 115200
});

port.pipe(parser);

port.on('open', () => console.log('Port open'));

// parser.on('data', console.log);
parser.on('data', function(data){
    console.log('main.js => retorno =>', data);
    sendToLoopback(data);
});


// The parser will emit any string response


/**
 * This function uses the request lib to sendo request to api loopback
 * @param {*} data 
 */
function sendToLoopback(data) {

    var request = require('request');
    if(data){        
        request.post(
            'http://localhost:3000/api/sender',
            { json: { corrente: data } },
            function (error, response, body) {
                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                    console.log('Sender to loopback =>', body)
                }
            }
        );        
    } else {
        console.log('No datas !');
    }
}
```

Comment: Que tipo de informação vais querer ter na tua aplicação? É importante que seja realtime e vais querer guardar a informação disponibilizada de X em X segundos para mais tarde consultar?

Comment: @Leite guardar a informação mesmo mano de x em x segundos, entende? inserir no banco de dados, já vai me ajudar no problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desculpem a demora para atualizar essa resposta aqui, eu realmente havia esquecido, bom eu utilizei uma biblioteca chamada **seriaport**, ela é excelente para se trabalhar com sensores estilo **arduíno**, **libelium** entre outros.

A **conexão** foi via usb, no caso a *COM3*, e o *baudRate*: 115200, usando essa biblioteca o próximo passo é apenas enviar os dados para o **back-end** no caso, o utilizado foi o **LoopBack**.

Abaixo também constam umas configurações extras para eliminar dados indesejados, espaços em branco e etc, para evitar inconsistência no banco de dados.

```
// This configurations uses serialport lib to catch usb values in serial COM (N) and baudRate
/* eslint-disable node/no-missing-require */
'use strict';

// Use a Readline parser

const SerialPort = require('serialport');
const parsers = SerialPort.parsers;

// Use a `\r\n` as a line terminator
const parser = new parsers.Readline({
  delimiter: '\r\n'
});

const port = new SerialPort('COM3', {
  baudRate: 115200
});

port.pipe(parser);

port.on('open', () => console.log('Port open'));

// parser.on('data', console.log);
parser.on('data', function(data){
    console.log('main.js => retorno =>', data);
    sendToLoopback(data);
});


// The parser will emit any string response


/**
 * This function uses the request lib to sendo request to api loopback
 * @param {*} data 
 */
function sendToLoopback(data) {

    var request = require('request');
    if(data){        
        request.post(
            'http://localhost:3000/api/sender',
            { json: { corrente: data } },
            function (error, response, body) {
                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                    console.log('Sender to loopback =>', body)
                }
            }
        );        
    } else {
        console.log('No datas !');
    }
}
```

Comment: Estou tentando fazer algo parecido, mas lendo dados do peso de uma balança e enviar para uma API. Tentei executar seu código, porém só vai até port.on('open', () => console.log('Port open')) os dados que são enviados não vai.

Comment: Opa, @IgorSilva se você preencher tudo corretamente, o certo seria enviar para sua API no sendToLoopback(data) observa que é em cascata que eu formulei o código. Tenta verificar se as informações estão corretas, é importante ressaltar que tanto tua conexão quanto o teu baudRate podem ser diferentes do que eu utilizei, é importante você tentar verificar isso. Essa foi a biblioteca que eu usei https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialport

Answer (score 2):

No Chrome 61 tens uma [WebUSB API disponível](https://wicg.github.io/webusb/), embora não tenha a certeza se vais conseguir o que queres usando isto, espero que ao menos te possa colocar no caminho correcto ou a pesquisar por soluções que possam ser adequadas. [Tens um blog post que pode ser útil](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/access-usb-devices-on-the-web) se é este tipo de solução que queres.

Outra opção, se queres usar Javascript e ter um registo da informação passada pelo dispositivo, é ter um serviço a correr com Node, que corre na máquina onde está o dispositivo ligado. Podes usar uma biblioteca tipo [esta](https://www.npmjs.com/package/usb), ou outras que existam (não pesquisei mais) para interagir com o teu dispositivo USB e recolher a informação, a partir dai fazes o que quiseres com ela.

A minha recomendação seria colocares esses dados numa base de dados, e isto já vai depender do que queres fazer com essa informação, se usas NoSQL, ou uma base de dados relacional. Podes usar uma alojada por ti, ou um servico 3rd party, por exemplo, da Google ou Amazon.

Eu, provavelmente iria criar um plano FREE (tem atenção que quando chegas aos limites podes ser cobrado) num serviço da [Google](https://firebase.google.com) (Firebase é exemplo, [tens outras opções](https://cloud.google.com/products/storage/)) ou [Amazon](https://aws.amazon.com/products/databases/?nc2=h_l3_db), e provavelmente guardava os dados em formato NoSQL para simplificar, ambos devem ter soluções para dados em realtime e mais adequados a receber dados de dispositivos IoT.

Por norma estas soluções dão-te uma API que podes aceder depois da tua aplicação em Angular sem teres de ter de criar tu uma API. Há também outras ferramentas, por exemplo o [Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/athena/) da Amazon, de onde podes ler os dados que guardaste e fazer queries para formatar os dados de certa forma.

Outra alternativa para a recolha de dados, pode ser usares um dos exemplos que encontraste em Java, C++ ou etc e substituir a tal aplicação em Node para o fazer, o resto dos passos eu faria da mesma forma.